# initializing an array of struct in C doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Why would this not work:

```
#define PORT_ID_MAX_CHAR                6

typedef struct  {
    int phys;
    char name[PORT_ID_MAX_CHAR];
}tPortMap;

struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = { 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" };
```

GCC barks at me saying `myfile.c:8:46: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = { 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" };` and I don't know why... I'm puzzled...

**EDIT1**

With extra braces I get the error:
`struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = {{ 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" }};`

`myfile.c:8:17: error: array type has incomplete element type
 struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = {{ 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" }};`

Comment: does `struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = {{ 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" }};` solve the problem?

Comment: I almost missed that `6` ...

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above

Comment: It's not `struct tPortMap`, it's just `tPortMap`

Comment: Yes I do, it's all in the same file.

Comment: @cerr See above, edited

Comment: @EugeneSh. **Ouch**, yes of course! Thanks for pointing it out!!! Add it as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Just let @RSahu add it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another pair of braces that surround the data for the elements of the array.

Also, you don't need to use `struct tPortMap` since you have already `typedef`ed `tPortMap`.

```
tPortMap c_portMap[] = { { 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" } };
                       ^^                            ^^
```

When you use

```
struct tPortMap c_portMap[] = { { 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" } };
```

the compiler thinks you are declaring a new `struct`, which obviously is not complete.

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** above

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PORT_ID_MAX_CHAR                6

typedef struct tPortMap {
    int phys;
    char name[PORT_ID_MAX_CHAR];
}tPortMap;

int main(void)
{
    tPortMap c_portMap[] = { { 0, "test" }, { 1,"test" } };

    printf("%s\n", c_portMap[0].name);
    return 0;
}
```